# Python write each line to file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write each line to file. Say my program output the following:

```
A man a bird a tree

A sleek ball in the terminal

We have our guests waiting
```

I want each line to be written to a new file or database. I'm assuming the concept is the same.

```
def break(tmp_file):
    n = 50
    with open(tmp_file) as c:
        out = []
        for line in c:
            for word in line.split():
                out.append(word)
                if word.endswith(('.', '!')) and len(out) >= n:
                    print(' '.join(out))
                    print("\n\n")
                                        f = open('save_file', "w+")
                            f.write(out)
                            f.close()
                    del out[:]

        # don't forget to flush the buffer
        if out:
            print(' '.join(out))
```

At the moment, It's saving all lines to same file. I expect it to save to unique file, like this:

```
Line1 - unique_file_1
Line2 - unique_file_2
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just change the ouput filename ?

Comment: How do I change the file names while the script is still running?

Comment: The text says something (write each line to a different file) the code does something else (split lines containing `.` or `!` or longer than 50 words), and you do not even say how the different files should be named. What help do you expect? Not a surprise that you get very different answers because each or us understand a different question :-(

Comment: My code split lines containing `. or !` How do I write each line to file using datetime for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you're saving outputs in same `save_file` file, you can try something like this.

```
import datetime

n = 50
with open("infile") as c:
    out = []
    for line_number, line in enumerate(c):


        for word in line.split():
            out.append(word)
            if word.endswith(('.', '!')) and len(out) >= n:
                print(' '.join(out))
                print("\n\n")

        if out:
            f = open(str((line_number+1).txt), "w+")
            f.write(' '.join(out))
            f.close()
            del out[:]

# don't forget to flush the buffer
if out:
    print(' '.join(out))
```

Comment: how would you suggest I save the file names like this: `01.txt, 02.txt, 03.txt ..`

Comment: You can use enumerate for that. Or have a counter variable.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
def break(tmp_file):
    n = 50
    with open(tmp_file) as c:
        out = []
        for ind, line in enumerate(c, 1):
            for word in line.split():
                out.append(word)
                if word.endswith(('.', '!')) and len(out) >= n:
                    print(' '.join(out))
                    print("\n\n")
                    f = open('Line{} - unique_file_{}'.format(ind), "w+")  #File name as requested 
                    f.write(out)
                    f.close()
                    del out[:]

        # don't forget to flush the buffer
        if out:
            print(' '.join(out))
```

Comment: Thank you, this enumerate shows "tuple index out of range" Is there a reason for that?